# How to use Entity, Form, Controller in a service for a websocket symfony app

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, websocket, ratchet

i’m working on a websocket app in Symfony2. I use a symfony2 bundle call ClankBundle (https://github.com/JDare/ClankChatBundle) who is based on Ratchet (http://socketo.me/).

I’ve successfully configure my service in symfony2 and server is working…
Exemple here, when i call in JS network.onSubscribe every people who have already subscribe receive the info.

```
class ChatTopic implements TopicHandlerInterface
{
/**
 * Announce to this topic that someone else has joined the chat room
 * Also, set their nickname to Guest if it doesnt exist.
 * 
 * @param \Ratchet\ConnectionInterface $conn
 * @param $topic
 */
  public function onSubscribe(Conn $conn, $topic)
  {
      if (!isset($conn->ChatNickname))
      {
          $conn->ChatNickname = "Guest"; **how i have to do if i want to use "$this->getUser(); " here ?**
      }

      $msg = $conn->ChatNickname . " joined the chat room.";

      $topic->broadcast(array("msg" => $msg, "from" => "System"));
  }
```

But now, I would like to use some other tools that I’ve already build like some Entity or Form “in my service”.

For example, I would like to be able to do “$this->getUser()” in my service to return the pseudo of the user. To return for example “Pseudo has joined this channel “ to every client connected to the channel.

This class is a part of my service and i would like use inside

```
$this->getUser
```

or

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($music);"
```

.

Or I would like to persist things send throw my websocket in Doctrine. (Like save every message send by any people connected to the websocket channel.

Like you see i'm not very confortable with Symfony2 and websocket but i'm learning !

I hope I’m clear (sorry for my english...) and someone can help me! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To persist entities, you need to first inject the entity manager into your class.

```
class ChatTopic implements TopicHandlerInterface
{
    protected $em;
    public function __construct($em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
}
```

You'll need to inject the dependency in services.xml

```
<services>
    <service id="jdare_clank.chat_topic_handler" class="JDare\ClankChatBundle\Topic\ChatTopic">
        <argument>"@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"</argument>
    </service>
```

And get your class from the service container in a controller or some other ContainerAwareInterface:

```
$chatTopic = $this->getContainer()->get('jdare_clank.chat_topic_handler');
```

Getting the user is trickier, since you won't have access to the security context in that class, since it is not container aware. There are a few ways you could do it. In our case, we actually implemented a secure websocket (wss) protocol and created a login protocol within, so we could store a user id with each connection. But one quick and dirty way would be to simply add the user id to your session in another controller.

```
$userId = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getId();
$session = $this->get('session');
$session->set('user', (str) $userId);
```

Then you can get the user from the session inside your class.

```
public function onSubscribe(Conn $conn, $topic)
{
    $userId = $conn->Session->get('user');
    $user = $this->em->getRepository('AcmeUserBundle:User')->find((int) $userId);
    ...
```

Hope this is helpful. Let me know if any of this loses you, and I'll try to help. Dependency injection is a little hard to wrap your head around, but it's a very powerfool tool in your kit!

Comment: This is very helpful ! But i don't get the "ContainerAwareInterface" part.. I have to use this service in an other controller like DefaultController.php ? Because i have already a PlaylistController who manage creation, modification and other stuf. So with $chatTopic = $this->getContainer()->get('jdare_clank.chat_topic_handler'); i can use my websocket in my PlaylistController ? Am i right ?

Comment: ContainerAwareInterface us any interface where you can use getContainer(), and Controllers are one such interface. So I think that will work!

Comment: ya but my onSubscribe function is called by javascripte when some client subscribe to the channel. so how can i trigger my controller when JS call onSubscribe? i cannot do $chatTopic->onSubscribe(params) because it's the JS who trigger this function ? am i clear ? (thanks for ur help btw)

Comment: You can put the javascript in a twig file for a controller action, and the controller action can set the user field in the session and pass the ChatTopic class to the twig.